# No apple news app after the mojave upgrade

Tags: macos, beta-seed-program, mojave, news.app, apple-news

I followed the steps to get a pirated version of mojave beta upgrade and everything is working fine except I don't see the much talked about apple news app, although other apps like voice memos, stocks and home are there. Its not a deal breaker but would like to know how to get it. Can't find it on the app store either.

Comment: Downloading beta software from an unreliable source has its risk...

Comment: @nohillside its not like it was downloaded from an unreliable source. The unreliable source was what triggered the availability of beta software in the app store

Comment: You should report problems with beta stuff to Apple in the channels they provide so they can fix them in the numerous further betas that will be coming out all summer.

Comment: @TomGewecke I am not sure this is a problem. probably some settings that need tinkering with

Comment: The download link in the video doesn't point to *.apple.com but rather to a sharing site, so you have no way of verifying whether the OS you install is the OS provided by Apple. Probably not the main issue regarding the News application, but dangerous nevertheless.

Comment: @bmike why are you so much inclined to declaring this copy of mojave as pirated? when it was downloaded and installed from the app store itself. the only thing that **can** be pirated over here is the file that triggered the availability of that upgrade which i downloaded from the link which you removed while editing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The App still exists, even if you don't live in one of the supported countries (or don't change your regional settings to one of them) - except it's hidden.

Here's how to start it:

1. Open Terminal
2. Type "open /Applications/News.app" (without the "")
3. Once it opens, right-click its icon on the Dock and choose "Keep on the dock"

Love it?

Answer (score 6):

You will want to delete the pirate copies of the installer and re-try a clean erase install from an image you get from Apple directly.

Once that's done, consider that once the app is installed, it may be blocked or not work in most regions.

> The News app is available in Australia, the United Kingdom, and the United States.

https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202329

Make sure you're in a region where the app is available, or have the region of macOS set to one of these regions.

Comment: that explains the problem, but how am I supposed to get the app after changing my region? I changed it and it does not magically appear in my launchpad so I guess there are some more steps involved

Comment: I think it depends on where you updated from. Where did you download Mojave from the app store?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the US edition of the Apple News app in any country without changing your language or region settings.

1. Open Safari
2. Type `applenews:` in the address field and press Enter

Alternatively, you can [create a shortcut](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/apple-news-macos-worldwide) and have the app appear in Finder, Launchpad, and Spotlight.

Comment: Good call on the OP getting the installer most likely from an unlicensed / pirate / non-apple source. Thanks for the good edit to the question and the proactive answer.

Comment: typing `applenews:` in safari doesn't work that way, but one fine day when opening a link to an RSS feed it magically asked me if I wanter to open News.app since then I see a little greyed out icon in the Applications folder but can't get it to show on the launchpad. Works pretty good though.

Comment: It would be interesting to find out *how* Apple hides News.app. There aren’t any flags set on the bundle, and the only extended attribute is `com.apple.rootless`, which means the application is protected by SIP. I wonder if there’s actually an exception programmed into Finder/Dock not to show it when you’re not in the right region.

Comment: @wjv, your questions is [answered here.](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/apple-news-macos-worldwide)

Comment: @Aeyoun So it is, thank you very much! (I didn’t read the article all the way to the end before!)